# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, java

Есть код:

```
public class Dialog2 extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener {

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    String data[] = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, data);

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle(R.string.adapter)
                .setSingleChoiceItems(adapter, -1, myClickListener)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, myClickListener);
        return adb.create();
    }

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    }

    OnClickListener myClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            ListView lv = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
            if (which == Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
                // выводим в лог позицию выбранного элемента
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "pos = " + lv.getCheckedItemPosition());
            else
                // выводим в лог позицию нажатого элемента
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "which = " + which);
        }
    };
}
```

В logcat при сборке выскакивает:

> Process: com.hangover.a56_alertdialogitemssingle, PID: 2076
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hangover.a56_alertdialogitemssingle/com.hangover.a56_alertdialogitemssingle.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Он ругается на:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, data);
```

Вроде же getActivity() должно быть, т.к. не в MainActivity. Что не так? И как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае `getActivity()` возващает `null`, так как фрагмент ещё не создан. Для быстрого решения проблемы переместите проблемную строку в начало метода `onCreateDialog`. Для более правильного решения проблемы инициализируйте ваши переменные в `onAttach` или в конструкторе (вот это не проверял):

```
public class Dialog2 extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener {

final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

String data[] = { "one", "two", "three", "four" };

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity act) {
   adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(act, android.R.layout.select_dialog_singkechoice, data);
    super.onAttach(act);
}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle(R.string.adapter)
            .setSingleChoiceItems(adapter, -1, myClickListener)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, myClickListener);
    return adb.create();
}

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

}

OnClickListener myClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        ListView lv = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
        if (which == Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
            // выводим в лог позицию выбранного элемента
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "pos = " + lv.getCheckedItemPosition());
        else
            // выводим в лог позицию нажатого элемента
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "which = " + which);
    }
};

}
```

Comment: Спасибо. А про onAttach можно поподробнее. Что это и для чего нужно?

Comment: @compl, я только второй день изучаю Fragment'ы, много чего сам не заю :)  
Во всяком случае, [документация](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) говорит, что onAttach вызывается первее всех.  
[Fragment Lifecycle](http://i.imgur.com/xnABRVh.png)